# How to choose from two different attribute

Tags: c#

I want to do some thing like this

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement(ElementName= "DealId")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnore]
 public int ID { get; set; }
```

and during the run time I choose from one element.
How could I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the attributes dynamically at runtime using the [`XmlAttributeOverrides`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributeoverrides(v=vs.110).aspx) class. Here's an example:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
}
```

and then when serializing:

```
var attributeOverrides = new XmlAttributeOverrides();
var attributes = new XmlAttributes();
if (SomeCondition())
{
    attributes.XmlIgnore = true;
}
else
{
    attributes.XmlElements.Add(new XmlElementAttribute("DealId"));
}

attributeOverrides.Add(typeof(MyModel), "ID", attributes);

// when instantiating the XmlSerializer we specify the attribute overrides
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyModel), attributeOverrides);
var model = new MyModel
{
    ID = 5,
};

serializer.Serialize(Console.Out, model);
```

In this example, based on some condition at runtime we specify that the `ID` property of our model will either have the `XmlElementAttribute` or `XmlIgnoreAttribute`.

Comment: Thank You For That It Works

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you want to optionally serialize the Id field.

But, you can define a method in the same class like this:

```
public bool ShouldSerializeID()
{
    return !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.ID);
}
```

and then remove the [XmlIgnore] attribute. In this example, the ID will be serialized where it has a value.